# Oracle Bi Publisher Word Multiply

Tags: oracle, ms-word, bi-publisher, extended-sql

I am creating a confirmation letter using Bi Publisher with Word Add In.

I need a field to convert a varchar to number then multiply this by 75% and of course if the field is zero to equal zero.

For example my room_rate is the field and currently is 3,000.00 and I need to show the net amount which is always 75% because 25% is taxes so I need it to display 2250.

I have tried writing the below but it results in a '0'

I apologise for my lack of skills as I am just beginning.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please share your current code, and XML.

Answer (score 1):

If you have these XML fields per row:

```
<room_rate>3,000.00</room_rate>
<net_percent>75</net_percent>
```

You would want to use this for the field you want to calculate:

```
<?xdofx:to_number(room_rate) * (net_percent div 100)?>
```

You really should be sending the value as a number in the XML, and storing it in the database as a number for that matter.

Comment: Thanks EdHayes3 for pointing me in the right direction. All I needed to do in the end was <?xdofx:room_rate*0.75?> so simple!

Comment: Ya, BI Publisher has some weird syntax some times.  If you are only multiplying that one value, and not turning it from text to number, you don't need that xdofx part.